# Windows Phone 8 integrated calculator application

Tags: windows-phone-8, calculator

Does anybody know how to achieve the rotation and orientation effect of the integrated calculator in windows phone 8 and 8.1.

Are there two different pages for landscape and portrait or is it one page with animations?

The buttons are with automatically calculated width and height to fit the screen. If animations are going to be used, you cannot set auto width and height to Landscape state.

Any ideas?

Comment: It likely does two animations (rotate then fade) to switch between the scientific and non-scientific Calculator view.